# Oracle Reports how to generate multiple output pdf's from one oracle reports

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

how to generate multiple output pdf's from one oracle reports.

I have a report where I have to generate more than one output files from the same report based on a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, when a report is run, it produces a **single** output (PDF file). If you want to get several files, you'll have to run the report as many times as needed, every time providing different parameter value.

It can be done manually or using an operating system batch script which would call RWRUN executable, passing required parameters. Here are some [examples](https://docs.oracle.com/html/E24479_01/pbr_cla002.htm#i667075).

Also, if the same RDF file is to be used to produce different **layout**, you can do that too by setting triggers (usually on frames) as they return a Boolean value so - depending on a parameter value - you'd display (or hide) certain parts of the report.